# SQL Server Spatial Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geometry, spatial

I am trying to create a curved line between two points so that I can use it with the mapping product MapBox and use it in the co-ordinates section. I am having some issues with it and am unclear about how to control the curve

The Microsoft documentation talks about curving the line

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stcurvetoline-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

I started playing with code from their site which is below. How do you have more control over the curve? At the moment it generates 65 points? I am looking at implementing this and using it with GeoJson but this would create a large number of co-ordinates

Questions:
- How do you control the number of points?
- How do you calculate the centre point?

```
 DECLARE @g1 geometry, @g2 geometry; 
 SET @g1 = geometry::Parse('CIRCULARSTRING(10 0, 0 10, 15 15)'); 
 SET @g2 = @g1.STCurveToLine(); 

 SELECT @g1.STGeometryType() AS [G1 Type], @g2.STGeometryType() AS [G2 Type], @g1.STLength() AS [G1 Perimeter], @g2.STLength() AS [G2 Perimeter]
 SELECT @g2.ToString() AS [G2 Def]; 
 SELECT @g1.STNumPoints(), @g2.STNumPoints();
```

Answer (score 0):

CIRCULARSTRING "defines" the curve

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/circularstring?view=sql-server-ver15

```
 DECLARE @g1 geometry, @g2 geometry; 
 SET @g1 = geometry::Parse('CIRCULARSTRING(10 0, 0 10, 15 15)'); 
 SELECT @g1 --and check the spatial results in sssms
```

"The Microsoft documentation talks about curving the line", it is actually the other way around, STCurveToLine() is lining the curve.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to find a central point between the two points to control the curve size?

Comment: the curve/arc is defined by 3 points, because if 3 points of an arc are known, the circe is defined: connect consecutive two points (A-B, B-C) with lines, draw perpendicular bisectors on each line, where they meet is the center of the circle. There is a function, STCentroid that returns the center of a geometry.

Comment: the link/page for the circularstring has a whitepaper with more in-depth information. you can find some interesting blogs about spatial data, just look around.